# class not found exception using netbeans and command prompt

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm having a rather annoying problem in my Java application which was put together in Netbeans. When I build the project it tells me everything is fine. I compile it in command prompt and it tells me everything is fine. When I run the .jar locally on my computer (from anywhere including external storage) the application opens just fine. When I open it on another computer or from command prompt it tells me there was a class not found exception.

I have done everything from editing the manifest to sacrificing a blank text document named "virgin" to invoke Boolius, the god of computers. Nothing is working out.

I have even made a second test app inside Netbeans with a main class that opens a JFram and NOTHING ELSE. It has the "public static void main(string[] args)" line there and accounted for. Same exact problem.

I have made all my constructors public.

I have made sure I'm using the latest java jdk.

I have ensured that my main class is in fact the main class.

I have read through all the manuals and tutorials the internet has to offer one after the other with no avail.

What can I do? What can I try?

Comment: set class path on that machine properly, or add that jar to class path already defined

Comment: watch that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6U7xkdj6RJs

Comment: VD', I really wish it was that easy. Ensuring that my machine variables are properly set is one of the first things I did when I discovered the problem.

getlost, Thanks for the video, I really was hoping it would have the key to my woes. Unfortunately there was no remedy to be found since all my projects have only one main class (I did follow the steps outlined in the video to be sure) and open just fine when double-clicked ... on MY computer. Once it's on another machine it refuses to open.